# SAS proc report ACROSS option

Tags: sas

I have the following code

```
proc report data = sashelp.class nowd; 
column    sex  ;  
define sex / across ; 
run ;
```

Here is the result

```
 Sex
 F  M
 9  *
```

---

Why does SAS display an asterisk `*` instead of a number ?

However when I run

```
proc report data = sashelp.class nowd; 
column   age sex  ;  
define age / group ;
define sex / across ; 
run ;
```

the result is normal

```
     Sex
Age F  M
11  1  1
12  2  3
13  2  1
14  2  2
15  2  2
16  .  1
```

---

**Do I have to use `GROUP` if I want to use `ACROSS` ? Why is there an `*` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `width`

```
proc report data = sashelp.class nowd; 
column    sex  ;  
define sex / width=2 across ; 
run ;
```